# best way for hard-coding sizes in c

Tags: c, types, size

I am writing a c application for decoding binary files and I need to be sure about the sizes of my chunks. Reading the documentation I understood that only the minimum size is stated while the maximum depends on the compiler or/and architecture...

so could I do something like : ***PSEUDOCODE

```
unsigned char byte;
if((byte = ~0) > 0xff){
    typedef (unsigned char & 0xff) byte; /* I know.. ;P */
}else{
    typedef unsigned char byte;
}
```

should I just apply the bit mask every time I use `unsigned char` to be sure or is there another way to hard code a size to a type that I don't know off?

ps: The reason this is important for me is because I going to be doing allot of shifting..
Thank you ;)

Comment: Use a C99 compiler (or a C89 compiler with extensions) and the fixed-width types: `uint8_t`, `int16_t`, .... If you can't find a compiler that defines the fixed-width types for your machine; applying the bit mask every time is the only solution.

Comment: This is a library for the android platform... and I don't know much about it's compiler.. I'll try to find a documentation about those types you propose. Thanks!

Comment: What happens with `uint8_t` on a platform with 32 bit chars?

Comment: a `uint8_t` is 8 bits regardless of the platform. I don't care if it has 128 bit chars.

Comment: @MikeNakis: If `CHAR_BIT==128` (more generally, if `CHAR_BIT>8`), then `uint8_t` will not exist.  Furthermore, the `intN_t` types are specified to be two's-complement with no padding bits; if `CHAR_BIT==8` but signed char uses ones'-complement, then `int8_t` will not exist.  (You're unlikely to run into either situation in practice.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the types `intN_t` and `uintN_t` from [stdint.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/basedefs/stdint.h.html) added in C99 (common values for `N` are 8, 16, 32, 64). They're guaranteed to have fixed size.

Comment: On the other hand, they're not guaranteed to exist if the particular sizes aren't supported.  But they will be supported on any system you're likely to run into (some DSPs have `CHAR_BIT > 8`).  And they were introduced in C99, so some out-of-date C implementations might not support them, but there's a [compatibility library](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/q8/index.html) for pre-C99 implementations.